# use an awesome package? - Getting started

Tags: ros, packages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can anyone direct me to a tutorial on how to use a package i find in a search.

Say i find a package or library using the ros wiki - how do I use it or implement it?

Thanks for your patience, I'm just getting started.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257780/use-an-awesome-package?---getting-started/) by [cerebraldad](https://answers.ros.org/users/29250/cerebraldad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2017-03-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The best way to install a ROS package, if you just want to use it, is to install it with `apt-get` under Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-PACKAGE
```

e.g.

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-slam-gmapping
```

To see, whether the package you are looking for is availabe through apt, just type:

```
apt-cache search ros-kinetic
```

If there is no apt package available, you typically have to go to the `src` directory in your catkin workspace, clone the git repository, that contains your package and run `catkin_make` from the root of your workspace.
You can get the URL to clone the repo from GitHub.

Step-by-step:

1. Go to the ROS-wiki page of your package and click on the GitHub link under the "Source:" bullet point.
2. On GitHub click on the green "Clone or Download" button and copy the URL from the text field.
3. Open a terminal and got to the `src` directory of your  catkin workspace.
4. Type:

```
# Clone the repository
git clone https://github.com/PATH-TO-YOUR-PACKAGE.git
cd ..

# Install dependencies via rosdep. Be sure to use the correct
# 'rosdistro' string, that fits to your ROS version.
rosdep update
rosdep install --from-paths src/ --ignore-src --rosdistro kinetic

# Run catkin
catkin_make
```

Hopefully, the package will build without errors. Sometimes you will have to install some additional packages or libraries via apt first which your package depends on.

Afterwards, you should probably source your setup.bash:

```
source PATH-TO-YOUR-WORKSPACE/devel/setup.bash
```

Now you are ready to run the nodes in your package, by using `rosrun` or `roslaunch`. But the usage of each package varies individually. Hopefully you will find the specific documentation on the ROS wiki.

A good example is IMHO the [Pepperl&Fuchs R2000](http://wiki.ros.org/pepperl_fuchs_r2000) driver.

---

Originally posted by [Andre Volk](https://answers.ros.org/users/29707/andre-volk/) with karma: 775 on 2017-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-24**:
This is a good answer (especially the "install using `apt-get` first", +1 for that), but could be better if you'd add a step between `cd ..` and `catkin_make` where you use `rosdep` to install a pkg's dependencies.

See #q252478 for how that would work.

**Comment by [Andre Volk](https://answers.ros.org/users/29707/andre-volk/) on 2017-03-24**:
Thanks for the comment. To be honest, I haven't used rosdep so far. It seems to be a convenient tool. I added the instructions to my answer above.